# Updating browser-solidity from git

Tags: remix

I like to have a local offline version of browser-solidity on localhost.
From now an then I want to update it to a newer version. Then disaster strikes

```
$ git status
On branch gh-pages
Your branch and 'origin/gh-pages' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

    new file:   browser-solidity-478fe25.zip

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both added:      README.md
    both added:      assets/css/universal-dapp.css
    both added:      build/app.js
    both added:      soljson.js
```

I virtually never touch that files, but they are always changed. Why is that?

Whats a good update solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just navigate to https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity, click the Branch dropdown to switch to gh-pages, then download the .zip file (the current version is browser-solidity-478fe25.zip) and unzip it into a directory on my computer. Each new version is unzipped into a different directory.

Using the .zip directly means I don't have to worry about Git and npm.

Comment: Probably the most practical thing

Answer (score 0):

I am updating it using git

first i have cloned the branch using :

```
git clone -b gh-pages https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity.git
```

then every time i update my local copy using

```
git pull
```

`git status` outputs

> On branch gh-pages Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/gh-pages'.
>   nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: now try to write some code and hell breaks lose. I know it's just to find the right commands, but I want to have the optimal solution by a git expert.